# Разработать интерфейс к двум разным источникам

Tags: qt, шаблоны-проектирования, архитектура, проектирование, сервисы

Есть два устройства разных производителей, выполняют одни и те же функции с помощью разных компонентов SDK (включение, выключение, передача данных и прочее). Задача написать код так, что бы при добавлении нового устройства, которое выполняет такие же функции, затратить меньше времени.

Если я правильно понял, то необходимо сделать сервис\ микросервис (который представляет из себя класс с набором функций) который будет объединять в себе работу с тем или иным устройством (которое реализовано как класс с набором переменных и функций)

Comment: Класс с описанием интерфейса и потомки под каждый вариант оборудования. Никаких сервисов не нужно.

Comment: Сделайте один интерфейс с сигнатурой методов и два класса с их реализациями.